# I can't get past this (React, react-bootstrap) Array.map() JavaScript syntaqx error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using react and react-bootstrap. I've been looking at this code all day and can't seem to fix it. I get the syntax error:  Line 30:26:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "}" (30:26)

```jsx
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import { Dropdown, DropdownButton } from "react-bootstrap";

import countries from "./../countries.json";

const SearchBar = () => {
    let selectedCountry = {};

    const selectCountryHandler = (e) => {
        selectedCountry = e.target.value;
        countryIsSelected = Object.keys(selectedCountry).length > 0;
        console.log(selectedCountry);
    };


    return (
        <>
            <h3>Select your filters</h3>
            <div className="bordered-component">
                <DropdownButton
                    id="countryDropdown"
                    variant="light"
                    title="Select a Country"
                    onSelect={selectCountryHandler}
                >
                    {
                        countries.forEach((country, ix) => {
                            <Dropdown.Item eventKey={country.id}>{country.name}</Dropdown.Item>
                        });
                    }
                </DropdownButton>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default SearchBar;
```

I've probably just been looking at it too long and it's something simple that I'm not seeing.

Comment: `forEach` will not render anything, it needs to be `map` and it needs to "return"..

Comment: And the syntax error is because of the semicolon after the forEach. Remove that, change the forEach for a map, remove the curl braces for an immediate return, and you should be set.

Answer (score 2):

The `forEach` function need the be a map with `return` statement :

```
<DropdownButton id='countryDropdown' variant='light' title='Select a Country' onSelect={selectCountryHandler}>
    {countries.map((country, ix) => {
        return <Dropdown.Item eventKey={country.id}>{country.name}</Dropdown.Item>;
    })}
</DropdownButton>
```